# Tracking interfaces added by a builder in the Java type system

Tags: java, generics, interface

If I have a builder-ish class, is there any way to keep track of the fact that certain interfaces have been added at the type level?

E.g. If I have

```java
var dinner = Noodling.build()
  .name("Spaghetti") // Returns PastaBase & IName
  .sauce("Marinara") // Returns PastaBase & ISauce, but I also want `& IName`
```

I'd like this to compile

```java
String name = dinner.getName();
```

But it doesn't, because `dinner` hasn't maintained the `IName` type.

This is currently the closest I've gotten this pattern to working, but it still has this issue.

```java
public class Noodling {

  public static PastaBase build() { return new Noodle(); }

  public interface IName { String getName(); }
  public interface ISauce { String getSauce(); }

  public interface PastaBase {
    public <T extends PastaBase & IName> T name();
    public <T extends PastaBase & ISauce> T sauce();
  }

  public static class PastaImpl implements PastaBase, IName, ISauce {

    @Override public <T extends PastaBase & IName> T name() { return (T) this; }
    @Override public <T extends PastaBase & ISauce> T sauce() { return (T) this; }

    @Override public String getName() { return name; }
    @Override public String getSauce() { return sauce; }

  }
}
```

I wouldn't be shocked if what I want is outside the possibilities of the Java type system, but it seems so close!

Comment: Didn't rename everything that I meant to. ISummary should have been IName. Edited.

Comment: You've not defined `Pasta`.

Comment: Edited. Maybe the underlying problem is clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Java doesn't have dynamic types. All types must be known at compile time, and there is no way to pass through that "you've called the `name` method so it's now an `IName` too".

There are workarounds, though. If your object is mutable (`name`, `sauce`, etc all return the same instance), you could assign the `name` call result to a variable of type `IName`, and call `getName()` on that. Or you could make classes for each combination of interface and return those based on which methods have been called. But that's *a lot* of code for most likely not much benefit.

Comment: That's about where I've landed. It feels like the type system is just a hair short, because it _does_ have all of the information at compile time (e.g. it knows that `name()` returns an `IName`) but there's no way to carry that between those calls without, yeah, building a horrible interface tree.